Background runner is not invoked
Even though I followed the steps as per the official documentation, the background runner code does not work.
I added the plugin to my capacitor.config.json:
"BackgroundRunner": {
      "label": "com.github.busaeed.myapp.runner",
      "src": "assets/runner.js",
      "event": "fetchNewData",
      "repeat": true,
      "interval": 15,
      "autoStart": true
    }

Here is the code of my src/assets/runner.js:
addEventListener('fetchNewData', (resolve, reject, args) => {
  try {
    console.log('received silent push notification');

    CapacitorNotifications.schedule([
      {
        id: 100,
        title: 'Enterprise Background Runner',
        body: 'Received silent push notification',
      },
    ]);

    resolve();
  } catch (err) {
    reject();
  }
});

Not even an error or warning message is displayed in the console which might help identify the issue.
